# Chinese remainder theorem under group point of view

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

> Let $G = U(\Bbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z})$, that is, the group of units in
>   $\Bbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z}$.  It is a group of size $p^{n-1}(p-1)=ab$, where
>   $a=p^{n-1},\; b=p-1$.  Let $A=\{g \in G : g^a=1\},\; B=\{g \in G :
> > g^b=1\}$. Show that $A$ is a subgroup of size $a$ and $B$ is a
>   subgroup of size $b$. Also, prove that $B$ is isomorphic to
>   $U(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})$ by mapping $x\, mod\,p^n$ to $x\,mod\,p$.

This is somehow related to the Chinese remainder theorem, I think. But I do not know how to apply it or write it down 'explicitly' (That is one of my big flaw). Could you give me some hints please?

Comment: Why do you think it is somehow the Chinese remainder theorem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all note that $gcd(a, b) = 1$. Let $g$ be a generator of the cyclic group $G$ then $A = \{g^b, g ^{2b}, \ldots, g^{ab} = 1\}$, so $A$ is a cyclic group of order $a$. $B = \{g^a, g ^{2a}, \ldots, g^{ba} = 1\}$, so $B$ is a cyclic group of order $b$. We have that $A \cap B = \{1\}$, so that G is the direct product $A \times B$. Since $\phi(p) = p-1 = b$, applying Lagranges small theorem repeatedly  we have that for elements of $B$ : $g^{ia} = g^i \mod p$ (because $g^p = g^{p^2} \ldots = g$), where $i$ ranges from $1$ to $b$. So we are led to show that the map $\mu: G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p : u \mapsto u \mod p$ is an injection restricted to $B$. This follows from the fact that $\mu$ is a multiplicative homomorphism of groups and that the order of $B$ is $b$.

Concerning the Chinese remainder theorem it relies on the followin simple fact. There is a bijective ring homomorphism between the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_q$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ (provided $\gcd(p, q) = 1$). This mapping is given by the inverse of the map $x \mapsto (x \mod p, x\mod q)$.

.